# String gets split into a list of characters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is some HTML code i am trying to parse for dayid

```
<div tabindex="0" role="link" aria-label="January-11-2010" class="CALBOX CALW6 CALSELF " dayid="01/11/2010">
<span class="CALNUM">11</span> 
<span tabindex="0" class="CALTEXT">Foreclosure<br>
      <span class="CALMSG"><span class="CALACT">0</span> / 
      <span class="CALSCH">50</span> FC<br></span>
      <span class="CALTIME"> 09:00 AM ET</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Code below here collects the dayid tag with some other data.

```
attrs = []
for elm in soup():  
    for attr, value in elm.attrs.items():
       if attr == 'dayid':
           attrs += elm.attrs.values() 
print(attrs)
```

This code should extract the date and store them as a list in MonthDays.

```
for i in range(len(attrs)+1):
    if(i%5 == 0 and i > 0):
      print(attrs[i-1])
      MonthDays += attrs[i-1]
```

The print produces the correct data as a list

```
'01/11/2010'
```

The issue is that my data does not get stored like shown above. It gets stored as shown below here

```
['0','1','/','1','1','/','2','0','1','0']
```

I would like it to be stored in a dataframe just as is on the print

Comment: Try to change `MonthDays += attrs[i-1]` to `MonthDays.append(attrs[i-1])`

Comment: try using this : `MonthDays += ''.join(attrs[i-1])` instead of this `MonthDays += attrs[i-1]`

Comment: Thank you both but the result is the same I still get the date broken out. Tried both suggestions

Comment: How are you initializing `MonthDays`? I tested @AndrejKesely's solution and it worked here.

Comment: Like so MonthDays = []... Should I initializing some other way?

Comment: Ok I forgot to reinitialize MonthDays list Andrej solution works

Comment: BTW, all values in `range(len(something))` are greater than 0, except for 0 itself. And you can set both `start` and `step`. So, `for i in range(4, len(attrs), 5):` should give you the `i`s that correspond to the `i-1`s in your code. It would skip many iterations and avoid an evaluation in each one. Of course, you could set those values to properly named variables to avoid using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I did not get your problem, but using `'append'` instead seems the logic way to add elements to *list* in Python, like:

```
for i in range(len(attrs)+1):
    if(i%5 == 0 and i > 0):
      print(attrs[i-1])
      MonthDays.append(attrs[i-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

So let's explain a bit what's happening.  For mutable sequences (like *list*) `+=` is the same as `.extend()`, see [Mutable Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).  So to quote documentation, your `MonthDays += attrs[i-1]` *"extends `MonthDays` with the contents of `attrs[i-1]`"*, adding all the items (string characters in this case) one by one to the list.  Using `.append()` is the correct option, but the "fix" with the least bytes changed would be `MonthDays += [attrs[i-1]]` (wrap the string in a list).  Don't do this at home!  It's  just a demonstration =)

---

Bonus: if I understood your task correctly, this is how you extract "dayid" values to a list:

```
month_days = [value for elem in soup()
                    for attr, value in elem.attrs.items()
                    if attr == 'dayid']
```